# Cross Platform List format

Tags: java, xml, json, client-server, communication

I have been using JSON and XML as request/response format for client-server or any general communication like java web-app and javascript client.

Like these are cross-plaform data exchange formats widely adapted by many languages and platforms, What I am wondering Is there any such popular data format for Lists only, I mean like JSON is a brilliant for key-value format and `""` is for String.

Comment: Lists of what? JSON could do that, e.g. `['one', 'two', 'three']` or even lists of objects `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart List of any general primitives, but can a JSON have a list directly like `['one', 'two', 'three']` please show some examples?

Comment: Of course it can. Here is an example: `["one", "two", "three"]`. Serialize `Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three")` with any Java JSON serializer, and you'll get the above-mentioned JSON.